# Query max(date) with group by not working on SELECT ... IN?

Tags: mysql

Each page in my system has multiple page_objects.
I need to return the last_changed records of my page_objects per page.

To decrease DB-impact, I have a SELECT ... IN query to return each last-edited page_object per page:

```
SELECT object, f_page_id, page_object_id, last_change
FROM page_objects 
WHERE f_page_id IN (page_id1, page_id2, page_id3, etc...) GROUP BY f_page_id
ORDER BY last_change ASC;
```

Of course this does not work, because `GROUP BY` is applied before `ORDER BY`, so I changed the query:

```
SELECT object, f_page_id, page_object_id,  max(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_change))
FROM page_objects 
WHERE f_page_id IN (page_id1, page_id2, page_id3, etc...) GROUP BY f_page_id
```

But this still does not return the last-edited `page_object` per page_id.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: try using sub query. although its selecting max and min value for group its returning the first f_page_id within group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query does not specify to get the record for the latest last_change. Merely that it gets the latest value of last_change. The other non aggregate values (ie, not the result of an aggregate function like MAX or MIN) that are not mentioned in the GROUP BY clause can come from any row for the grouped values.

As such you use a sub query to get the latest value for each page, and then join that back against your main table to get the matching rows

Something like this:-

```
SELECT page_objects.object, 
        page_objects.f_page_id, 
        page_objects.page_object_id, 
        page_objects.last_change
FROM page_objects 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT f_page_id, MAX(last_change) AS latest_last_change
    FROM page_objects 
    GROUP BY f_page_id
) sub0
ON page_objects.f_page_id = sub0.f_page_id
AND page_objects.last_change = sub0.latest_last_change
WHERE page_objects.f_page_id IN (page_id1, page_id2, page_id3, etc...) 
ORDER BY last_change DESC
```

Note that MySQL is quite unusual at allowing you to have non aggregate columns that are not mentioned in the GROUP BY clause (as it is against SQL standards, except under very particular circumstances). Most flavours of SQL will issue an error if you try this, and MySQL has a configuration parameter which will similar cause it to reject such queries.

Comment: I have tried your example, but it returns zero results. According to your response I guess I need to try this an other way? What do you advise in this situation, a query per page? (so instead of 1 query, like 20 queries)

Comment: @Abayob -  Something like the above should work. Can you post your table declares and a bit of sample data then I have a chance to test it. Although looking at my code again now I think the problem is probably that the sub query has converted the last_change date to a UNIX_TIMESTAMP - updated the code so try it now.

Comment: Aaah ofcourse, wake up me! I will check that first and if it still not works, Ill create a sql-example.

Comment: Dude you did it! Thank you very much!! I changed the `sub0.latest_last_change` to `from_unixtime(sub0.latest_last_change)` and it works as a charm!

Comment: Oh, I also added the tablename `page_objects` to every parameter of the first line and to the last, because it wouldn't work otherwise. Could you update your answer, so I can accept it? :D

Comment: Updated it. Not sure if you have any need to convert to a unix timestamp, and if so no need to do it except in the final SELECT